# Animation flickering with a ngFor on iOS: Start value is wrong?

Tags: ios, angular, animation, ionic-framework, angular-animations

I'm displaying a list of cards that are pulled from a server. I want them to appear gradually when I get the results from the server, so I set it up that way:

```
<ion-row [@listAnimation]="filteredTicketGroups.length">
     <ion-col col-4 *ngFor="let ticketGroup of filteredTicketGroups>
         <ion-card>
            // CONTENT HERE
         </ion-card>
     </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

And this is my .ts file:

```
@Component({
selector: 'page-ticket-groups',
  templateUrl: 'ticket-groups.html',
  animations: [
    trigger('listAnimation', [
      transition('* => *', [ // each time the binding value changes
        query('ion-col', [
          style({ opacity: 0 }),
          stagger(50, [
            animate('0.4s', style({ opacity: 1 }))
          ]),
          style({ opacity: 1 })
        ], { optional: true })
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
```

Now, this works fine on browser. The cards start invisible (opacity:0) and gradually become visible, one by one.

On iOS, the cards are visible for a split second and **then** start the animation (opacity:0 etc...).

It seems like the animation starts with the wrong value, but only on iOS. Is there any way to fix that?